# HtmlUnit download attachments

Tags: java, attachment, htmlunit

I need to save files from websites Using `HtmlUnit`. I am currently navigating to pages that have several anchors that use javascript `onClick()="DownloadAttachment('attachmentId')"` to get the files. The files can be of pretty much any type ( xls, doc, txt, pdf, jpg, etc). So far though I've been unable to find resources or examples that show how to save files using `htmlUnit`. I've been trying mainly to get `AttachmentHandler` to work for this as it seems the most likely to work, but have been unsuccessful. I was wondering if anyone else has managed to download files using `HtmlUnit` and could assist?

Comment: Source for `AttachmentTest.java`: https://htmlunit.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/htmlunit/trunk/htmlunit/src/test/java/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/attachment/AttachmentTest.java

Comment: @TheBeeKeeper: can you please answer the question yourself and then accept that answer? Also, you need to accept answers to previous questions if they fix your problem.

Comment: For all the people who are confused: The answer to the question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/6497098/revisions

Comment: I copied the question and answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21758258/htmlunit-and-javascript-in-links