# HtmlUnit and JavaScript in links

Tags: java, javascript, http, htmlunit

[Copied from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497098/htmlunit-download-attachments):

I need to save files from websites using [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). I am currently navigating to pages that have several anchors that use javascript:

```
 onClick()="DownloadAttachment('attachmentId')"
```

So far though I've been unable to find resources or examples that show how to save files using HtmlUnit. I've been trying mainly to get [AttachmentHandler](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/attachment/AttachmentHandler.html) to work for this as it seems the most likely to work, but have been unsuccessful.

How do I use AttachmentHandler to get at the data stream which the browser would see if I clicked on the link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's more simple than that. Just simulate the click event and then get the `WebResponse`:

```
HtmlElement anchorAttachment = (HtmlElement) pageETrackerItem.getByXPath(".../a").get(0);

InputStream is = anchorAttachment.click().getWebResponse().getContentAsStream();
```

Comment: Is there a way to utilize AttachmentHandler or existing examples of how it should be used for downloading files?